# How to match the iterative head in a iterative list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I want to delete the `f[g[...]]` last appear in a iterative list.Such as:

```
{f[1], g[2], {3, f[g[5]], {1, f[g[5]], f[g[8]]}, 1}, 
 f[g[9]], 6, {f[9], {g[5], f[g[6]]}}, {f[f[6]], f[g[6]], 8}, f[3]}
```

I want to delete the last `f[g[6]]` but don't change the list structure to get

```
{f[1], g[2], {3, f[g[5]], {1, f[g[5]], f[g[8]]}, 1}, 
 f[g[9]], 6, {f[9], {g[5], f[g[6]]}}, {f[f[6]], 8}, f[3]}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Position` to find the pattern, take the last one, and set it to nothing.  As a function:

```
ClearAll@lastfg;
lastfg[list_] := Module[{temp = list},
  (temp[[##]] = Sequence[]) & @@ Last@Position[temp, f[g[_]]];
  temp]
```

Comment: `Cases` or `DeleteCases` can do this?

Comment: @yode The trouble with `Cases` is that you have no idea which is the last occurance, so you can't pick just that one.  (Unless you want to run it twice with some silly counting thing the second time).  With `DeleteCases` you can specify you want to delete the first $n$.  Unfortunately you can't put in a negative number to delete the last $n$.